# selecting rows which contain certain characters

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I am working with a product database and i need to select `products` that are greater than £150 also only entries that have "HP" in the third and forth position of the `prod_id`.

So far i have tried

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_id LIKE 'hp%';
```

Here is a pic of the table i need to query

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An underscore will match a single character.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE prod_id LIKE '__hp%'
AND price > 150;
```

Should find all products whos 3rd and 4th character are hp and have a price of 150 or more

Comment: getting Error: Token mismatch

Comment: @Jmac88 Token mismatch doesnt sound like a sql error.  Could this be a php error?  Can you run this query in a query designer and get the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_id LIKE '__hp%' and price > 150;
```

"_" (underscore) is any symbol (there are 2 undrscores in this query)